# Can I initialize a python object by reusing it's value?

Tags: python

Can I initialize a python object by reusing it's value?

Ex :
If I want to initialize list A, with setting it's 3rd(index=2) value as it's 1st(index=0) value, I might intuitively use
`a = [1, 2, a[0]]` (which is not available).

Comment: If `a` is not defined yet, how can `a[0]` be?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this

```
a = [1,2]
a.append(a[0])
```

It is the only way since the right side of the code if first finished before assigning it to the left side. It is just the way python works